# Problems discretizing a notch filter - Chebyshev Type I

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, digital-filters

I'm trying to implement and discretize a notch filter (Chebyshev type I) these specifications:

Ws = 2*pi*[2000 2500];
Wp = 2*pi*[1000 7000];
Rp = 0.5;
Rs = 40;

But when I try to use discretization methods, Tustin has a weird phase graph, and ZOH has also a weird behaviour. I couldn't find anything online that would explain those behaviours. Could anyone help me?

[image]
Discretization matlab code:

```
% continuos to discrete
Ws = 2*pi*[2000 2500];
Wp = 2*pi*[1000 7000];
Rp = 0.5;
Rs = 40;
[n,Wp] = cheb1ord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs,'s');
[b,a] = cheby1(n,Rp,Wp,'stop','s');
H = tf(b,a);

Hbi = c2d(H,1/20000,'tustin');
Hzoh = c2d(H,1/20000,'zoh');
Hm = c2d(H,1/20000,'matched');
Hdp = c2d(H,1/20000,'prewarp',2*pi*2250);
%Hii = c2d(H,1/20000,'impulse');
    
options = bodeoptions;
options.FreqUnits = 'Hz'; % or 'rad/second', 'rpm', etc.
    
bode(H,'b',Hzoh,'r',Hbi,'m',Hm,'g', Hdp, 'y',{2*pi*100 2*pi*10000}, options), grid
legend('Continuous','ZOH','Tustin','Matched','Tustin w/ pre-warping')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `bode()` for the discrete transfer functions? That's only for your initial t.f., the rest need `freqz()`.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/discretizing-a-notch-filter.html Actually I was following this matlab documentation, that uses bode after c2d

Comment: Why don't design it directly in the discrete domain ?

Comment: @Hilmar, that's because I'm doing a study specifically on these transformation methods. Do you know why I'm having these behaviours?

Comment: @Caroline Hmm, looks like Octave can't do that. Maybe there are numerical problems? Try not using kHz, but Hz, to tame the numbers.

Comment: Have you read https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/continuous-discrete-conversion-methods.html

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'll try that, but I don't think thats the problem...

Comment: @Hilmar yess I've read it, but I didn't notice anything in that doc that would apply to the behaviour Im gettin from the ZOH method.

Comment: Im out of ideas of what it could be, Ive researched a lot already